# Dataflow template "Pub/Sub Avro to Bigquery" fails to decode

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, avro, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to stream data from Pub/Sub to Bigquery via the Dataflow template "Pub/Sub Avro to Bigquery". The data in Pub/Sub is in AVRO format and coming from a Kafka topic. The corresponding schema file I got from the schema registry. This is what it looks like:

```
{"type":"record","name":"KsqlDataSourceSchema","namespace":"io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas","fields":[{"name":"ID","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"TIMESTAMP","type":["null","string"],"default":null}]}
```

There is no newline in the saved schema.avsc and I'm getting this error in dataflow:

```
2021-01-22 10:31:28.231 MEZError message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not decode Pubsub message org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1139) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:140) Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: 47 unexpected extra bytes after decoding {"ID": null, "TIMESTAMP": null} org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:101) org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:92) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1137) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:140) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:227) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:186) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1400) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:156) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1101) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not decode Pubsub message org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1139) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:140) Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: 47 unexpected extra bytes after decoding {"ID": null, "TIMESTAMP": null} org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:101) org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:92) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1137) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:140) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:227) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:186) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1400) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:156) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1101) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not decode Pubsub message org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1139) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:140) Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: 47 unexpected extra bytes after decoding {"ID": null, "TIMESTAMP": null} org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:101) org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:92) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1137) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:140) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:227) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:186) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1400) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:156) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1101) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not decode Pubsub message org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1139) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:140) Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: 47 unexpected extra bytes after decoding {"ID": null, "TIMESTAMP": null} org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:101) org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:92) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO.lambda$parsePayloadUsingCoder$839baa85$1(PubsubIO.java:1137) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.lambda$fn$36334a93$1(Contextful.java:112) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:140) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:227) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:186) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1400) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:156) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1101) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I'm consuming the messages in my topic manually, I'm able to decode with the exact same schema, however I need to take care of five extra bytes in front of my message. The original message out of Pub/Sub looks like this:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x02\x1656173684800\x02:2021-01-22T10:21:40.384+01:00'
```

I suspect, that I need to change something to my schema.avsc file in order for Dataflow to handle the extra bytes correctly, but I'm not sure how and maybe not sure if it's even the right approach.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the exception and the information you provided, seems like the issue is in the input data that you consume from the Pub/Sub topic.

The template ends up reading using `readAvroGenericRecords` method here.
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.java#L515

This ends up using Beam's `AvroCoder` to binary decode the data to produce Avro `GenericRecord` objects using the Java Avro library.
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9e0920c401258ec38bddbd9298747378126b8fe4/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.java#L327

So potentially, as a manual test, you can try  decoding data using the Java Avro  library to determine if you can generate Avro GenericRecord objects.